# How to transform an associative array into a set of HTML table rows in PHP / CakePHP?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

[table data on this type image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm3jv.png)  My array is `$otaDetails` which prints

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [OtherOtaBooking] => Array ( [id] => 1 [listing_id] => 0 [event_id] => 123testing [first_name] => [last_name] => [email_id] => [phone_number] => 0 [title] => [checkin] => 0000-00-00 [checkout] => 0000-00-00 [no_of_guests] => 0 [amount_paid] => 0 [amount_rec] => 0 [reservation_id] => 0 [booking_src] => ) ) [1] => Array ( [OtherOtaBooking] => Array ( [id] => 2 [listing_id] => 0 [event_id] => 123testing [first_name] => testamar 12 [last_name] => [email_id] => aaaaa@gmail.com [phone_number] => 2147483647 [title] => CasaMelhor: 2BHK in Candolim:CM001 [checkin] => 2015-12-16 [checkout] => 2015-12-17 [no_of_guests] => 21 [amount_paid] => 2147483647 [amount_rec] => 111111 [reservation_id] => 0 [booking_src] => asdddddddd ) )
```

I want to print it in table format

```
<?php 
foreach ($otaDetails as $otaDetail){
    echo'<tbody>';
    echo'<tr>'; 
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['id']."</td>";
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['listing_id'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['first_name'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['last_name'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['email_id'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['phone_number'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['title'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['checkin'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['checkout'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['no_of_guests'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['amount_paid'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['amount_rec'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['reservation_id'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['booking_src'].'</td>';
    echo'<tr>';
    echo'</tbody>';
}
?>
```

However, this gives the error:-

> Undefined index: id [APP\Plugin\PropManagement\View\Otherotabookings\index.ctp, line 59]

Comment: Except the fact that the <tbody> should be outside the foreach, do you have any error ?

Comment: but giving below error                                                                     Undefined index: id [APP\Plugin\PropManagement\View\Otherotabookings\index.ctp, line 59]

Comment: You are having a three-dimensional Array, but you're treating it like a two-dimensional array.

Comment: To get the first ID, you have to do 0 => OtherOtaBooking => ID. What you're doing is 0 => ID.

Comment: What's with huge indentation?

Comment: check my ans it's work fine

Comment: @AmarDesai accept my if it's work.check mark them

Comment: If you feel any of the answers below replied to your question, please mark it as 'Accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3):

try my code it's work $otaDetail is a multidimentional array so you need to use like  `$otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking'][index]`

```
  <?php foreach ($otaDetails as $otaDetail){
                                        echo'<tr>'; 
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['id']."</td>";
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['listing_id'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['first_name'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['last_name'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['email_id'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['phone_number'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['title'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['checkin'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['checkout'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['no_of_guests'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['amount_paid'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['amount_rec'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['reservation_id'].'</td>';
                                        echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['booking_src'].'</td>';
                                        echo'</tr>';
                                        }
                                        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CakePHP (as you mention), you can obtain the same result by issuing:

```
<tbody>
    <?=$this->Html->tableCells(Hash::extract($otaDetails,'{n}.OtherOtaBooking'))?>
</tbody>
```

You can filter the columns you wish to print by using the `$fields` option in `$this->OtherOtaBooking->find()`.

Comment: This is the most elegant way!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your array is multidimensional, and you're trying to reference keys of the child array while iterating the parent array.

Try this:

```
<?php foreach ($otaDetails as $otaDetail){
                                    echo'<tr>'; 
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['id']."</td>";
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['listing_id'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['first_name'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['last_name'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['email_id'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['phone_number'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['title'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['checkin'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['checkout'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['no_of_guests'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['amount_paid'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['amount_rec'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['reservation_id'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['booking_src'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<tr>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
```

Of course, if you have multiple child arrays, simply run a `foreach` loop within the existing loop.

Comment: its giving me Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Doh. My bad. I've edited the answer to correct for that.

Answer (score 0):

check your last `<tr>` tag. close it `</tr>`

```
<?php foreach ($otaDetails as $otaDetail){
                                    echo'<tbody>';
                                    echo'<tr>'; 
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['id']."</td>";
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['listing_id'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['first_name'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['last_name'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['email_id'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['phone_number'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['title'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['checkin'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['checkout'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['no_of_guests'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['amount_paid'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['amount_rec'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['reservation_id'].'</td>';
                                    echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['booking_src'].'</td>';
                                    echo'</tr>';
                                    echo'</tbody>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
```

Comment: That's not what the problem is.

Comment: its giving me Undefined offset: 0

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code line with this line

`echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['id']."</td>"`

you will get your answer
you forgot add one more index that is [OtherOtaBooking]

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($otaDetails as $otaDetail){
        echo'<tr>'; 
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['id']."</td>";
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['listing_id'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['first_name'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['last_name'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['email_id'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['phone_number'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['title'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['checkin'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['checkout'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['no_of_guests'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['amount_paid'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['amount_rec'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['reservation_id'].'</td>';
            echo'<td>'. $otaDetail['OtherOtaBooking']['booking_src'].'</td>';
        echo'</tr>';
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```